# Probability choosing basketball teams to play games

Tags: probability

> Given 12 teams of basketball, 3 of them are English teams. We
>   divide the teams into pairs (randomly and equally possible).    What is the
>   probability that  no English team played against an English team?   Assume a team can play only once (once it was chosen then she cannot play again).

My go:
I tried really hard to think how to solve it without thinking about combinatorics, or, very little about it, but I got stuck right away.
If I understand correctly, the probability is just: $1-P(\text{2 English teams play together})$
However this is just too many options, as not only we have $3$ possible scenarios where 2 English teams play together, but we have those "sub-scenarios" where the 9 other teams got paired BEFORE we choose to pair up the English teams...

I was devastated and so my final answer is $\frac{3C2}{12C2} \approx 0.95$
3C2 is the number of options to pair 3 English teams with one another = 3
12C2 is the total number of options to pair the teams

which I highly doubt is the answer..
I would appreciate your help! Thank you!

Comment: What does the final in your title refer to?  The question seems to involve the first round.  Usually a tournament would have a power of $2$ entries or would give byes in the first round to reduce to a power of $2$.

Comment: @RossMillikan no no, it is not a tournament that the winning team gets to the next match, it is only ONE match. sorry the title was incomplete I got very hyped to write the question so I moved on ha ha, I changed it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pick one of the English teams.  The chance it plays another English team is $\frac 2{11}$.  Assuming it does not play another English team, pick another.  The chance it plays the remaining English team is $\frac 19$.  The overall chance of two English teams meeting is then 
$$\frac 2{11}+\frac 9{11}\cdot \frac 19=\frac 3{11}$$

Comment: This answer does not include the fact that it is not a tournament but just choosing groups of 2 teams out of 12 and that's it (no playing - or winning losing, I just need to calculate the probability no 2 english teams played together) , right? thank you!

Comment: Yes, it assumes you just randomly form six matches of the twelve teams and quit.  This is the chance two English teams are matched among the six matches.

Comment: And so 1- 3/11 is the probability of not having 2 english teams being paired , yes?

Comment: That is correct.